# Как сделать кнопку поверх картинки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, css-animation

Есть галерея из картинок типа:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="img" width="250" height="250">
```

Что можно придумать на js или css для того, чтобы при наведении мышки на изображение по центру появлялась другая картинка размерами, допустим 50х50px, как на некоторых сайтах при наведении мыши на картинку, в центре появляется кнопка зума (увеличения)...

Причем так должно работать на всех картинках галереи, и при появлении этой кнопки картинка не должна пропадать или размазываться (это я сейчас про `visible`, `hidden` или же `opacity`), картинка должна затемняться через `rgba()`, а по центру кнопка (маленькая картинка типа зума).

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Засуньте маленькую картинку в псевдоэлемент обертки и показывайте при наведении (если нужно при наведении) или сразу же.

```css
.zoomable-pic {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
}

.zoomable-pic:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/50/50);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.zoomable-pic:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.zoomable-pic__image {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="zoomable-pic">
  <img class="zoomable-pic__image" src="http://placeimg.com/200/200" />
</button>
```